# TYpescript : Static methods on Function as class

Tags: class, typescript, static, static-methods, late-binding

I have a `fn` that inherit an existing `fn` ( take Angular1 $q for example )

```
//$q original behavior
var defer = $q.defer();
defer.promise.then(function(result){})
//or
$q( (resolve, reject) => {
   //promise execution here
}).then(function(result){});
```

If I want to decorate it, I would do :

```
var Qdecorator = function($delegate) {

     var Q = function(resolver:any): any {
       //do some extra stuff here
       return $delegate.apply($delegate, arguments);
     }

     //Assign the static methods here: 

     Q.defer = function() {
        //do some stuff 
        return $delegate.defer.apply($delegate, []);
     }
     //same goes for race, when, resole reject and so on
     return Q;
}
```

Problem is that typescript complains about 
    Property `defer`, `race, when, resolve, etc...` `does not exist on type '(resolver: any) => any'`

I tried to use the `IQService`, and `IPromise` with no luck, btu I'd like to raise a more global question :

How do I define late static methods on function() that return an object without using `new`

Comment: Where and how are you defining `$q`?

Comment: @JamesMonger https://github.com/a-lucas/angular.js-server-bower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am copying pasting the answer to my question from this link: 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

```
interface Counter {
  (start: number): string;
  interval: number;
  reset(): void;
}

function getCounter(): Counter {
  let counter = <Counter>function (start: number) { };
  counter.interval = 123;
  counter.reset = function () { };
  return counter;
}

let c = getCounter();
c(10);
c.reset();
c.interval = 5.0;
```